# jQuery interference between Two scripts

Tags: jquery, html, magento

I am using 2 different scripts. One for the Menu & one for a lightbox I am trying to add.

Declared both scripts in head section but I cannot get both to work at the same time. I know its because I am trying to use two different jQuery versions at the same time, but does anyone have a way around this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custommenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

First one is for my custom menu & the second one is being used by the lightbox script I got from [Kyle Schaeffer's Blog](http://kyleschaeffer.com/tutorials/lightbox-jquery-css/).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How about this for a solution : use only one version of jQuery !

Answer (score 0):

rearrange your page header like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custommenu.js"></script>
```

And also try to use a single "jquery.min.js"

Comment: Thats what I have it as. custommenu.js is just a bunch of functions to make the menu work. For the lightbox I am adding the function on the page I want it to work on but it still needs the jquery.min.js I added in the header.

Comment: Personally, there really isn't a lot of need to use JS for a nav menu. It's so much nicer to just build it with CSS. Of course, I assume you are after snappy transitions or something, hence the use, but the use of javascript by the Magento Core team for the nav menu is complete overkill.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please list **all** the JS files you're loading into this page. List them in the same order you load them please.
2. Try loading only one version of jQuery and load it before all other scripts
3. If you *really* need to use two version if jQuery on one page, you have to put one of them into noConflict-mode ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ ). But I then you'll have to change your script so that it will not user `$` but the noConflict-variable instead (see jQuery docs).